# How can I pass to a slot more than the arguments the signal sends in pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals

I am writing a python plasmoid for KDE4.

I have a QHttp object which emits the signal "done (bool)" and i assign it to my functionB. I want to pass to functionB the valueA too. If I pass the value using **lambda**, the signal never triggers functionB.

```
def functionA(self):
  self.http=QHttp()
  ...
  valueA="valueA"
  self.connect(self.http, SIGNAL("done (bool)"), lambda valueA: self.functionB)
  self.get("/myurl.html")

def functionB(self, done, valueA):
  ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda does not call functionB. Try if this works:

```
lambda done: self.functionB(done, valueA)
```

EDIT. Perhaps this approach would be better:

```
def functionA(self):
  self.http=QHttp()
  ...
  self.valueA="valueA"
  self.connect(self.http, SIGNAL("done (bool)"), self.functionB)
  self.get("/myurl.html")

def functionB(self, done, valueA=None):
  if valueA is None: 
      valueA = self.valueA
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I Also wanted to disconnect and self.disconnect(self.http, SIGNAL("done (bool)"), lambda done: self.functionB(done, valueA)) does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: @volk Can you make valueA an instance variable as in my edit?

Comment: Yes i did it as your edit so i can simply disconnect as well. Thank you very much.